# Smith Waterman algorithm how to match a shorter sequence to a longer one

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming, bioinformatics

This is a pseudo code i wrote for the original smith waterman algorithm.

```
Input: U[1, n], V[1, m]
Set W[0, j] = 0 for j = 0 .. m
Set W[i, 0] = 0 for i = 0 .. n
For i = 1 to n
    For j = 1 to m
        W[i, j] = max {
                       0, 
                       W[i, j-1] - d, 
                       W[i-1, j-1] + s(U[i], V[j]), 
                       W[i-1, j] - d
                       }
```

Now I need to fit a shorter sequence U (1-n) into a longer sequence V (1-m), How can I modify the code?

Comment: Smith-Waterman is a local alignment algorithm. That means it should already be able to handle sequences of different lengths. What exactly do you want it to be able to do that it can't already?

Comment: mapping a mature-mrna (without introns) to a genome sequence or pre-mrna. There is no gap penalty for dna, but there should be for mrna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminating the penalty for gaps in the DNA sequence while keeping it for gaps in the mRNA sequence should be pretty straightforward. Assuming that U is the DNA and V is mRNA (otherwise, this will be the other way around), you just remove the gap penalty term (-d) from the value for the scenario where you are inserting a gap in i (W[i, j-1]), as so:

```
W[i, j] = max {
               0, 
               W[i, j-1], 
               W[i-1, j-1] + s(U[i], V[j]), 
               W[i-1, j] - d
               }
```

However, this will probably not be a robust solution to your problem. You still want to favor alignments without gaps in the DNA over alignments with them. A simple solution would be to use a different, smaller gap penalty for gaps in the DNA. However, in light of the fact that you want to account for one sequence having introns and the other not having them, you would probably be best served by an affine gap penalty.

An affine gap penalty is one in which there is a greater penalty for starting a gap than for continuing one. So it will favor creating extended intron-like gaps, making it much more likely to give you a biologically-plausible alignment (even in more standard biological sequence alignment problems, affine gap penalties tend to be more successful). Unfortunately, implementing an affine gap penalty is a bit more complicated. You end up needing to keep track of three score/pointer matrices. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101078/traceback-in-smith-wateman-algorithm-with-affine-gap-penalty?rq=1) or [these slides](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckingsf/bioinfo-lectures/gaps.pdf) for pseudo-code and more information.

Comment: do you think 0 should be removed? and also the initial steps should be 0 for DNA and -j for mRNA?

Comment: Having 0 as an option is what makes this a local alignment algorithm (i.e. one that only aligns the parts of sequences that are a good fit for each other). If you want to guarantee that all parts of the DNA sequence are included in the alignment, you should use a semi-global alignment algorithm (one that ignores gaps on the ends). To turn this into a semi-global algorithm, yes, you should remove 0 as an option and initialize W[i, 0] to 0. Normally, you would also initialize W[0, j] to 0, but since there really shouldn't be a gap at the beginning of the mRNA, you can initialize it to -j*d.

Comment: (although it shouldn't really end up mattering whether you initialize W[0,j] to 0 or -j*d, because it should not turn out to be optimal to use a value from it. If it does, that would probably be evidence of something fishy going on in your algorithm or your data)